# Selenium Script fails on Firefox Browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm Using -

> Selenium 3.0.1 with java
>
> Firefox version : 50.1.0
>
> geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64

I have created one complete testsuit of my web application. When I run it on `chrome` browser, all test runs smoothly. no issue at all but for browser compatibility test, I switched to `firefox` driver and run the test, My test getting always failed . Problem happening with input fields, I guess the speed of entering text is too fast due to this, even the text not getting filled in text boxes but it is clicking the submit button as I'm able to see blank field validation messages.I'm sucked how to deal with this. Do I need to debug&run my whole script on FF or is there any feasible solution ?

**Eidted**

I have one `DriverSetup` class where following code is placed -

```
public class DriverSetup 
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setUp( @Optional String browser) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            switch(browser)
            {
                    case "chrome":

                        System.out.println("Starting chrome........");
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/Application/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
                        driver = new ChromeDriver();        
                        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                        driver.get(TestData.mainSiteURL);
                        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        ScreenCapture.passedScreenShot();
                    break;

                    case "firefox":
                        System.out.println("Starting Firefox........");
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/Application/geckodriver.exe");
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
                        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                        driver.get(TestData.mainSiteURL);                   
                        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        ScreenCapture.passedScreenShot();
                    break;
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception In : "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()+"-->"+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
            ScreenCapture.failedScreenShot();
        }
    }
}
```

And Another is `SubmitNewContact` class

```
public class SubmitNewContact extends DriverSetup
{

    @Test
    public void submitNewContact() throws IOException
    {

        try
        {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Contact")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Name")).sendKeys(TestData.contactName);
            driver.findElement(By.id("Phone")).sendKeys(TestData.contactPhone);
            driver.findElement(By.id("EmailID")).sendKeys(TestData.contactEmail);
            driver.findElement(By.id("message")).sendKeys(TestData.contactMessage);
            ScreenCapture.passedScreenShot();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();   
            ScreenCapture.passedScreenShot();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Exception In : "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()+"-->"+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
            ScreenCapture.failedScreenShot();
        }

    }
}
```

And Running both classes using testNG -

```
  <test name="ExecuteTestFirefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
         <classes>                  
                    <class name="com.testmaster.DriverSetup"/>
                    <class name="com.test.user.SubmitNewContact"/>
         </classes> 
  </test>
```

**Note** :- Also having some other classes like `SubmitNewContact` for each functionality of my application and running then all using `testing.xml`

Comment: Could you share the part of your code where the test fails first, so I can help you?

Comment: I read ' debug script' - if it's a JavaScript related question, please update the tag :)

Comment: @minhundje, code is added, please have a look

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @mosaad, no error .but not able to fill the data in forms

Comment: try using gecko win32 and not 64

Answer (score 1):

The same code works on chrome? In my experience geckodriver still has this kind of issues which makes it hard to use. If you can't create workaround for this and switching to chromedriver(or other drivers) is not an option I would recommend you to use 'old' Firefoxdriver instead of geckodriver/marionette.

But ofcourse, post your problematic code here so we could work something out first. :)

Comment: and where does it fail?

Comment: not entering texts in text fields, It seems actions are too fast that's why it is skipping.

Comment: Too fast how? Maybe after click you need to wait for this field to render, did you try with some waiters?

Comment: I have created my script using `chrome` so I have managed the waits wherever I was getting the issue. Now I want to run the same suite on `firefox` So It seems to put some extra efforts to debug whole suit on FF and modify according. suppose I did that then how do I be sure that it works fine on some  other browser or that previous one ?  is there any generic solution to get rid from this ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no generic solution that can assure that it will work fine on every browser. But as I said before, marionette/geckodriver is not ready yet to be fully used (that's my opinion), so consider using old firefox driver and wait for geckodriver to fully grow. :)

Comment: I'm agree with your opinion :) old was better one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133557/discussion-between-narendra-rajput-and-acikojevic).

Answer (score 0):

As you're having trouble, a good help/solution is always additional wait time. In order to do that I suggest you use a function like this, to wait for an element to be found:

```
public static void implicitlyWaitForElementPresent(FirefoxDriver driver, By elementToBePresent) {
    // Waits up to 45 seconds while searching for the given Element to be present
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        driver.findElement(elementToBePresent);
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could use this method in the following manner:

```
public void clickSomething() {
    Utility.implicitlyWaitForElementPresent(mDriver, By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div/ul[3]/li/a"));
    WebElement something = mDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div/ul[3]/li/a"));
    something.click();
}
```

Please note that I've put the wait-function in a different class for OOP reasons.
You can change this code according to your needs.

If you have any further questions, I'm here to help you.

Comment: thanks for your help, But I'm not getting any `exception` . `sendkeys` action is too fast so skipping if I put `Thread.sleep(1000)` before each statement then it fill the data as expected

Comment: Yeah I used to have these problems, too. Additional wait time is almost always the answer in test automation.

Comment: I had tried your suggestion but no luck :( . It was fine with `Thread.sleep()` method

Answer (score 0):

I run into exactly the same problem. On some forms the `sendKeys()` method is sending the keys, I can see them in the screenshot, but nevertheless I get the message that I have to fill the form. On other pages it works well. Also in chrome I use exactly the same code and I have no problems.

Does anyone has a solution for `selenium 3.0.1`?

Info: I'm using the firefox docker setup.

```
public void sendKeys(By objectPath, CharSequence key){
    RemoteWebDriver browserDriver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browserDriver, BuildDriverHandler.timeout);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(objectPath));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(objectPath)).sendKeys(key);
}
```

[sendkeys send something, but still I have to fill the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p9D1.png)